# SignalR dependency could not resolve in mvc 6.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, dnx

1. New ->Project -> Asp.net Web Application
2. Asp.net Preview Template -> Web Application

When I try to add reference "Signalr" in "MVC6" application I am getting  this error 
MVC6    D:\abc\abc\MVC6\MVC6\src\MVC6\project.json  29"

```
  Project.json File


            [![{
          "webroot": "wwwroot",
          "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-MVC6-1f7e65af-9175-4945-8e68-ee0805d494e9",
          "version": "1.0.0-*",

          "dependencies": {
            "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
            "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
            "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",

            "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR": "2.2.0"


          },

          "commands": {
            "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
            "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
          },

          "frameworks": {
            "dnx451": { }
          },

          "exclude": \[
            "wwwroot",
            "node_modules",
            "bower_components"
          \],
          "publishExclude": \[
            "node_modules",
            "bower_components",
            "**.xproj",
            "**.user",
            "**.vspscc"
          \],
          "scripts": {
            "prepublish": \[ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" \]
          }
        }][1]][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMvK6.png
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       Dependency Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR >= 2.2.0 could not be resolved  MVC6    D:\abc\abc\MVC6\MVC6\src\MVC6\project.json  29"

Comment: beta5? There were 5 releases after beta5 and RTM is shipping next week...

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.2.0 of SignalR is only for classic .Net framework, ASPNET Core will use [version 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server/), still in beta.